# Create Custom Windows Service Timer : Basically Add Name to Timer

Tags: .net, timer, windows-services

I have a function where I pass a Timer, e.g.

```
Private Sub Process(myTimer as timer)
  Select Case myTimer.ToString()
        Case "Timer1"
        Case "Timer2"
        Case "Timer3"
  End Select
End Sub
```

However, when I pass a specific Timer- I cannot figure out inside Process()
which Timer is currently processing.

Timer has the properties,

[image]

How can I get the name of the Timer?

How about a Custom Timer? - how do i set the Timer to MyTimer when creating a CustomTimer?

```
Public Class CustomTimer
  Inherits Timer

  Public Property TimerName As String
  Public Sub New(t As Timer)

  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems enumerating or identifying .net object by name (string) has growing popularity, especially in Visual Basic community.
In my opinion this is wrong, .NET API suggest using Tag for all programmers requirement that framework hasn't

```
Timer t1;
Timer t2;
...
t1.Tag = new MyAdditionalInfo("foo");
t2.Tag = new MyAdditionaInfo("bar");

.. or simply 
t1.Tag = "foo";
t2.Tag = "bar";
```